# Is it possible to optimize this code for maximum performance?

Tags: javascript, performance, optimization, graphics, p5.js

I programmed this type of Penrose Tilings in javascript and the algorithm is 'simple':

The cyan pentagon always have to draw the yellow losangle and the grey pentagon almost always have to draw two red pentagons and a half star, that will draw a grey and red pentagons that will draw a star and so on.

[image: Penrose Tiles]

Sometimes we'll need to check colisions and the amount of shapes.

I'll plan to expand to draw even more tiles, but would like to know if it's possible to optimize the code to avoid unnecessary calls to sine and cossine functions, less lines and even unnecessary variables and ifs.

Can you help me about this?

```
  <html>
  <head>
    <meta charset = "utf-8">
    <title>Penrose</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.6.0/p5.js"></script>
  <script>

  var x, y, shape;
  var angle;
  var size = 20;
  var tolerance = 0.00001;
  var otherShapesAmount;
  var sides;

function list()
{
  this.begin = null;
  this.size = 0;

  function no(x, y, angle, shape, otherShapesAmount, sides, next = null)
  {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.angle = angle;
    this.shape = shape;
    this.otherShapesAmount = otherShapesAmount;
    this.sides = sides;
    this.next = next;
  }

  this.insert = function(x, y, angle, shape, otherShapesAmount, sides)
  {
    this.begin = new no(x, y, angle, shape, otherShapesAmount, sides, this.begin);
    this.size++;
  }

  this.differenceBetweenVertex = function(x, y, shape)
  {
    let atual = this.begin;

    while (atual)
    {
      if (atual.shape == shape) if (Math.abs(atual.x - x) < tolerance && Math.abs(atual.y - y) < tolerance) return true;
      atual = atual.next;
    }
    return false;
  }

  this.getData = function()
  {
    if (this.size == 0) return 0;
      else if (this.size == 1)
      {
        x = this.begin.x;
        y = this.begin.y;
        angle = this.begin.angle;
        shape = this.begin.shape;
        otherShapesAmount = this.begin.otherShapesAmount;
        sides = this.begin.sides;
        
        this.begin = null;
      }
        else
        {
          var anterior;
          var auxiliar = 0;
          let atual = this.begin;
          while (auxiliar < this.size - 1)
          {
            anterior = atual;
            atual = atual.next;
            auxiliar++;
          }
          x = atual.x;
          y = atual.y;
          angle = atual.angle;
          shape = atual.shape;
          anterior.next = atual.next;
          otherShapesAmount = atual.otherShapesAmount;
          sides = atual.sides;
       }
    this.size--;
    return 1;
  }

  this.clean = function()
  {
    this.begin = null;
    this.size = 0;
  }
}

class points
{
  constructor(x, y)
  {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
}

  var pentagonVertex = [];
  var losangleVertex = [];
  var harfStarVertex = [];
  var starVertex = [];

function setup()
{
  pentagonVertex[0] = new points();
  pentagonVertex[1] = new points();
  pentagonVertex[2] = new points();
  pentagonVertex[3] = new points();
  pentagonVertex[4] = new points();

  losangleVertex[0] = new points();
  losangleVertex[1] = new points();
  losangleVertex[2] = new points();
  losangleVertex[3] = new points();

  harfStarVertex[0] = new points();
  harfStarVertex[1] = new points();
  harfStarVertex[2] = new points();
  harfStarVertex[3] = new points();
  harfStarVertex[4] = new points();
  harfStarVertex[5] = new points();
  harfStarVertex[6] = new points();

  starVertex[0] = new points();
  starVertex[1] = new points();
  starVertex[2] = new points();
  starVertex[3] = new points();
  starVertex[4] = new points();
  starVertex[5] = new points();
  starVertex[6] = new points();
  starVertex[7] = new points();
  starVertex[8] = new points();
  starVertex[9] = new points();

  createCanvas(800, 800);
}

function drawPentagon(pentagonVertex)
{
  beginShape();
  vertex(pentagonVertex[0].x, pentagonVertex[0].y);
  vertex(pentagonVertex[1].x, pentagonVertex[1].y);
  vertex(pentagonVertex[2].x, pentagonVertex[2].y);
  vertex(pentagonVertex[3].x, pentagonVertex[3].y);
  vertex(pentagonVertex[4].x, pentagonVertex[4].y);
  vertex(pentagonVertex[0].x, pentagonVertex[0].y);
  endShape();
}

function drawLosangle(losangleVertex)
{
  beginShape()
  vertex(losangleVertex[0].x, losangleVertex[0].y);
  vertex(losangleVertex[1].x, losangleVertex[1].y);
  vertex(losangleVertex[2].x, losangleVertex[2].y);
  vertex(losangleVertex[3].x, losangleVertex[3].y);
  vertex(losangleVertex[0].x, losangleVertex[0].y);
  endShape();
}

function drawHalfStar(harfStarVertex)
{
  beginShape();
  vertex(harfStarVertex[0].x, harfStarVertex[0].y);
  vertex(harfStarVertex[1].x, harfStarVertex[1].y);
  vertex(harfStarVertex[2].x, harfStarVertex[2].y);
  vertex(harfStarVertex[3].x, harfStarVertex[3].y);
  vertex(harfStarVertex[4].x, harfStarVertex[4].y);
  vertex(harfStarVertex[5].x, harfStarVertex[5].y);
  vertex(harfStarVertex[6].x, harfStarVertex[6].y);
  vertex(harfStarVertex[0].x, harfStarVertex[0].y);
  endShape();
}

function drawStar(starVertex)
{
  beginShape();
  vertex(starVertex[0].x, starVertex[0].y);
  vertex(starVertex[1].x, starVertex[1].y);
  vertex(starVertex[2].x, starVertex[2].y);
  vertex(starVertex[3].x, starVertex[3].y);
  vertex(starVertex[4].x, starVertex[4].y);
  vertex(starVertex[5].x, starVertex[5].y);
  vertex(starVertex[6].x, starVertex[6].y);
  vertex(starVertex[7].x, starVertex[7].y);
  vertex(starVertex[8].x, starVertex[8].y);
  vertex(starVertex[9].x, starVertex[9].y);
  vertex(starVertex[0].x, starVertex[0].y);
  endShape();
}

  var mainList = new list();
  var vertexList = new list();
  var start = true;

function draw()
{
  translate (800 / 2, 800 / 2);
  if (start == true) //beginning - the cyan pentagon will nedd to be draw using the hypotenuse to be draw in the center of the translated point
  {
    angle = 18;
    let hypotenuse = size / (2 * sin((36 * PI) / 180));
    pentagonVertex[0].x = hypotenuse * cos((angle * PI) / 180);
    pentagonVertex[0].y = hypotenuse * (-sin((angle * PI) / 180));
    mainList.insert(pentagonVertex[0].x, pentagonVertex[0].y, angle - 18, 1, 1, undefined);
    mainList.insert(pentagonVertex[0].x, pentagonVertex[0].y, angle - 54, 2, 10, undefined);
    angle += 72;
    pentagonVertex[1].x = hypotenuse * cos((angle * PI) / 180);
    pentagonVertex[1].y = hypotenuse * (-sin((angle * PI) / 180));
    mainList.insert(pentagonVertex[1].x, pentagonVertex[1].y, angle - 18, 1, 1, undefined);
    mainList.insert(pentagonVertex[1].x, pentagonVertex[1].y, angle - 54, 2, 10, undefined);
    angle += 72;
    pentagonVertex[2].x = hypotenuse * cos((angle * PI) / 180);
    pentagonVertex[2].y = hypotenuse * (-sin((angle * PI) / 180));
    mainList.insert(pentagonVertex[2].x, pentagonVertex[2].y, angle - 18, 1, 1, undefined);
    mainList.insert(pentagonVertex[2].x, pentagonVertex[2].y, angle - 54, 2, 10, undefined);
    angle += 72;
    pentagonVertex[3].x = hypotenuse * cos((angle * PI) / 180);
    pentagonVertex[3].y = hypotenuse * (-sin((angle * PI) / 180));
    mainList.insert(pentagonVertex[3].x, pentagonVertex[3].y, angle - 18, 1, 1, undefined);
    mainList.insert(pentagonVertex[3].x, pentagonVertex[3].y, angle - 54, 2, 10, undefined);
    angle += 72;
    pentagonVertex[4].x = hypotenuse * cos((angle * PI) / 180);
    pentagonVertex[4].y = hypotenuse * (-sin((angle * PI) / 180));
    mainList.insert(pentagonVertex[4].x, pentagonVertex[4].y, angle - 18, 1, 1);
    mainList.insert(pentagonVertex[4].x, pentagonVertex[4].y, angle - 54, 2, 10, undefined);

    fill('cyan');
    drawPentagon(pentagonVertex);
    start = false;
  }
    else
    {
      while (mainList.getData())
      {
        switch (shape)
        {
          case 0: if (vertexList.differenceBetweenVertex(x, y, 0) == false) //cyan pentagon
                  {
                    pentagonVertex[0].x = x;
                    pentagonVertex[0].y = y;

                    angle += 72;
                    pentagonVertex[1].x = x + size * cos((angle * PI) / 180);
                    pentagonVertex[1].y = y + (size * (-sin((angle * PI) / 180)));

                    angle += 72;
                    pentagonVertex[2].x = pentagonVertex[1].x + size * cos((angle * PI) / 180);
                    pentagonVertex[2].y = pentagonVertex[1].y + size * (-sin((angle * PI) / 180));

                    angle += 72;
                    pentagonVertex[3].x = pentagonVertex[2].x + size * cos((angle * PI) / 180);
                    pentagonVertex[3].y = pentagonVertex[2].y + size * (-sin((angle * PI) / 180));

                    angle += 72;
                    pentagonVertex[4].x = pentagonVertex[3].x + size * cos((angle * PI) / 180);
                    pentagonVertex[4].y = pentagonVertex[3].y + size * (-sin((angle * PI) / 180));

                    fill('cyan');
                    drawPentagon(pentagonVertex);
                    mainList.insert(pentagonVertex[2].x, pentagonVertex[2].y, angle + 144, 1, 1, sides);
                    vertexList.insert(pentagonVertex[1].x, pentagonVertex[1].y, null, 0, undefined, undefined);
                    vertexList.insert(pentagonVertex[3].x, pentagonVertex[3].y, null, 0, undefined, undefined);
                    vertexList.insert(pentagonVertex[4].x, pentagonVertex[4].y, null, 0, undefined, undefined);
                  }
                    else
                    {
                      let auxiliar = 0;
                      pentagonVertex[0].x = x;
                      pentagonVertex[0].y = y;

                      if (vertexList.differenceBetweenVertex(x, y, 1) == true) auxiliar++;
                      angle += 180;
              
                      pentagonVertex[1].x = x + size * cos((angle * PI) / 180);
                      pentagonVertex[1].y = y + size * (-sin((angle * PI) / 180));
                      if (vertexList.differenceBetweenVertex(pentagonVertex[1].x, pentagonVertex[1].y, 1) == true) auxiliar++;

                      angle -= 72;
                      pentagonVertex[2].x = pentagonVertex[1].x + size * cos((angle * PI) / 180);
                      pentagonVertex[2].y = pentagonVertex[1].y + size * (-sin((angle * PI) / 180));
                      if (vertexList.differenceBetweenVertex(pentagonVertex[2].x, pentagonVertex[2].y, 1) == true) auxiliar++;

                      angle -= 72;
                      pentagonVertex[3].x = pentagonVertex[2].x + size * cos((angle * PI) / 180);
                      pentagonVertex[3].y = pentagonVertex[2].y + size * (-sin((angle * PI) / 180));

                      if (vertexList.differenceBetweenVertex(pentagonVertex[3].x, pentagonVertex[3].y, 1) == false)
                      {
                        mainList.insert(pentagonVertex[3].x, pentagonVertex[3].y, angle + 36, 1,1);
                        vertexList.insert(pentagonVertex[3].x, pentagonVertex[3].y, null,1);
                      }
                      auxiliar++;

                      angle -= 72;
                      pentagonVertex[4].x = pentagonVertex[3].x + size * cos((angle * PI) / 180);
                      pentagonVertex[4].y = pentagonVertex[3].y + size * (-sin((angle * PI) / 180));
                      if (vertexList.differenceBetweenVertex(pentagonVertex[4].x, pentagonVertex[4].y, 1) == true) auxiliar++;

                      if (auxiliar == 3) mainList.insert(pentagonVertex[1].x, pentagonVertex[1].y, angle + 216, 2, 10, undefined);
                        else
                        {
                          mainList.insert(pentagonVertex[0].x, pentagonVertex[0].y, angle - 72, 2, 7, 1);
                          mainList.insert(pentagonVertex[3].x, pentagonVertex[3].y, angle + 72, 2, 7, 0);
                          mainList.insert(pentagonVertex[4].x, pentagonVertex[4].y, angle, 2, 3, undefined);
                        }
                    }
          break;
          case 1: losangleVertex[0].x = x; //losangle
                  losangleVertex[0].y = y;

                  losangleVertex[1].x = x + (size * cos((angle * PI) / 180));
                  losangleVertex[1].y = y + (size * (-sin((angle * PI) / 180)));

                  angle += 36;
                  losangleVertex[2].x = losangleVertex[1].x + size * cos((angle * PI) / 180);
                  losangleVertex[2].y = losangleVertex[1].y + size * (-sin((angle * PI) / 180));

                  angle += 144;
                  losangleVertex[3].x = losangleVertex[2].x + size * cos((angle * PI) / 180);
                  losangleVertex[3].y = losangleVertex[2].y + size * (-sin((angle * PI) / 180));

                  fill('yellow');
                  drawLosangle(losangleVertex);
                  mainList.insert(losangleVertex[2].x, losangleVertex[2].y, angle - 288, 0, 1, undefined);
                  vertexList.insert(x, y, null, 1, 0, undefined);
                  vertexList.insert(losangleVertex[2].x, losangleVertex[2].y, null, 1, 0, undefined);
          break;
          case 2: otherShapesAmount--; //gray pentagon
                  pentagonVertex[0].x = x;
                  pentagonVertex[0].y = y;

                  angle += 72;
                  pentagonVertex[1].x = x + size * cos((angle * PI) / 180);
                  pentagonVertex[1].y = y + (size * (-sin((angle * PI) / 180)));

                  angle += 72;
                  pentagonVertex[2].x = pentagonVertex[1].x + size * cos((angle * PI) / 180);
                  pentagonVertex[2].y = pentagonVertex[1].y + size * (-sin((angle * PI) / 180));

                  angle += 72;
                  pentagonVertex[3].x = pentagonVertex[2].x + size * cos((angle * PI) / 180);
                  pentagonVertex[3].y = pentagonVertex[2].y + size * (-sin((angle * PI) / 180));

                  angle += 72;
                  pentagonVertex[4].x = pentagonVertex[3].x + size * cos((angle * PI) / 180);
                  pentagonVertex[4].y = pentagonVertex[3].y + size * (-sin((angle * PI) / 180));

                  fill('gray');
                  drawPentagon(pentagonVertex);
                  if (otherShapesAmount > 1)
                  {
                    mainList.insert(pentagonVertex[1].x, pentagonVertex[1].y, angle + 36, 3, 1, sides);
                    if (otherShapesAmount > 5) mainList.insert(pentagonVertex[2].x, pentagonVertex[2].y, angle + 180, 4, otherShapesAmount - 2, sides);
                    mainList.insert(pentagonVertex[3].x, pentagonVertex[3].y, angle - 324, 3, 1, sides);
                  }
                    else mainList.insert(pentagonVertex[2].x, pentagonVertex[2].y, angle + 108, 3, 1, sides);
          break;
          case 3: otherShapesAmount--; //red pentagon
                  pentagonVertex[0].x = x;
                  pentagonVertex[0].y = y;
                  angle += 72;
                  pentagonVertex[1].x = x + size * cos((angle * PI) / 180);
                  pentagonVertex[1].y = y + (size * (-sin((angle * PI) / 180)));

                  angle += 72;
                  pentagonVertex[2].x = pentagonVertex[1].x + size * cos((angle * PI) / 180);
                  pentagonVertex[2].y = pentagonVertex[1].y + size * (-sin((angle * PI) / 180));

                  angle += 72;
                  pentagonVertex[3].x = pentagonVertex[2].x + size * cos((angle * PI) / 180);
                  pentagonVertex[3].y = pentagonVertex[2].y + size * (-sin((angle * PI) / 180));

                  angle += 72;
                  pentagonVertex[4].x = pentagonVertex[3].x + size * cos((angle * PI) / 180);
                  pentagonVertex[4].y = pentagonVertex[3].y + size * (-sin((angle * PI) / 180));
            
                  fill('red');
                  drawPentagon(pentagonVertex);
                  if (otherShapesAmount > 0) mainList.insert(pentagonVertex[3].x, pentagonVertex[3].y, angle - 324, 5, otherShapesAmount, sides);
          break;
          case 4: otherShapesAmount--; //half star
                  harfStarVertex[0].x = x;
                  harfStarVertex[0].y = y;

                  angle -= 36;
                  harfStarVertex[1].x = x + size * cos((angle * PI) / 180);
                  harfStarVertex[1].y = y + size * (-sin((angle * PI) / 180));

                  angle -= 72;
                  harfStarVertex[2].x = harfStarVertex[1].x + size * cos((angle * PI) / 180);
                  harfStarVertex[2].y = harfStarVertex[1].y + size * (-sin((angle * PI) / 180));

                  angle += 144;
                  harfStarVertex[3].x = harfStarVertex[2].x + size * cos((angle * PI) / 180);
                  harfStarVertex[3].y = harfStarVertex[2].y + size * (-sin((angle * PI) / 180));

                  angle += 36;
                  harfStarVertex[4].x = harfStarVertex[3].x + size * cos((angle * PI) / 180);
                  harfStarVertex[4].y = harfStarVertex[3].y + size * (-sin((angle * PI) / 180));

                  angle += 36;
                  harfStarVertex[5].x = harfStarVertex[4].x + size * cos((angle * PI) / 180);
                  harfStarVertex[5].y = harfStarVertex[4].y + size * (-sin((angle * PI) / 180));

                  angle += 144;
                  harfStarVertex[6].x = harfStarVertex[5].x + size * cos((angle * PI) / 180);
                  harfStarVertex[6].y = harfStarVertex[5].y + size * (-sin((angle * PI) / 180));
                  fill('green');
                  drawHalfStar(harfStarVertex);
                  if (otherShapesAmount > 5)
                  {
                    mainList.insert(harfStarVertex[2].x, harfStarVertex[2].y, angle - 36, 2, 2, undefined);
                    mainList.insert(harfStarVertex[3].x, harfStarVertex[3].y, angle, 3, 2, undefined);
                    mainList.insert(harfStarVertex[5].x, harfStarVertex[5].y, angle- 36, 2, 2, undefined);
                  }
                    else if (sides == 0) mainList.insert(harfStarVertex[5].x, harfStarVertex[5].y, angle - 36, 2, 2, sides);
                      else mainList.insert(harfStarVertex[2].x, harfStarVertex[2].y, angle - 36, 2, 2, sides);
          break;
          default: starVertex[0].x = x; //star
                   starVertex[0].y = y;

                   angle += 72;
                   starVertex[1].x = x + size * cos((angle * PI) / 180);
                   starVertex[1].y = y + size * (-sin((angle * PI) / 180));

                   angle -= 72;
                   starVertex[2].x = starVertex[1].x + size * cos((angle * PI) / 180);
                   starVertex[2].y = starVertex[1].y + size * (-sin((angle * PI) / 180));

                   angle += 144;
                   starVertex[3].x = starVertex[2].x + size * cos((angle * PI) / 180);
                   starVertex[3].y = starVertex[2].y + size * (-sin((angle * PI) / 180));

                   angle -= 72;
                   starVertex[4].x = starVertex[3].x + size * cos((angle * PI) / 180);
                   starVertex[4].y = starVertex[3].y + size * (-sin((angle * PI) / 180));

                   angle += 144;
                   starVertex[5].x = starVertex[4].x + size * cos((angle * PI) / 180);
                   starVertex[5].y = starVertex[4].y + size * (-sin((angle * PI) / 180));

                   angle -= 72;
                   starVertex[6].x = starVertex[5].x + size * cos((angle * PI) / 180);
                   starVertex[6].y = starVertex[5].y + size * (-sin((angle * PI) / 180));

                   angle += 144;
                   starVertex[7].x = starVertex[6].x + size * cos((angle * PI) / 180);
                   starVertex[7].y = starVertex[6].y + size * (-sin((angle * PI) / 180));

                   angle -= 72;
                   starVertex[8].x = starVertex[7].x + size * cos((angle * PI) / 180);
                   starVertex[8].y = starVertex[7].y + size * (-sin((angle * PI) / 180));

                   angle += 144;
                   starVertex[9].x = starVertex[8].x + size * cos((angle * PI) / 180);
                   starVertex[9].y = starVertex[8].y + size * (-sin((angle * PI) / 180));

                   fill('orange');
                   drawStar(starVertex);
        }
      }
      noLoop();
    }
}
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here's the code:

Comment: code review might be a better place for this sort of question

Comment: You've only got a small number of angles, so you can store the sin/cos values in a lookup table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'll plan to expand to draw even more tiles, but would like to know if it's possible to optimize the code to avoid unnecessary calls to sine and cossine functions, **less lines and even unnecessary variables and ifs**.

I'm focusing on your request to make the code shorter and cleaner (which won't improve the runtime performance). **I got rid of 180 lines of code by creating just two utility functions.**  You can keep going in this direction and get it much cleaner.

You want to look for blocks of code which are similar.  They probably won't be identical, but whatever is different will be represented by one or more variables.

---

The first section which can be cleaned up is your `drawPentagon`, `drawLosangle`, etc. functions.

What is different between each function is:

1. The array of vertices (`pentagonVertex` vs. `losangleVertex`)
2. The number of vertices to draw

But #2 can be derived from #1 because it is based on the length of the vertex array.  So we can create a single function which draws any of these shapes and it only needs one variable.

```
function drawFromVertices(vertexArray) {
  beginShape();
  for (let i = 0; i < vertexArray.length; i++) {
    vertex(vertexArray[i].x, vertexArray[i].y);
  }
  endShape(CLOSE);
}
```

I'm using a loop to draw each point in the array.  I'm passing the special [`CLOSE` argument to the p5 `endShape` function](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/endShape) in order to repeat the first vertex at the end.

You can delete your four individual draw shape functions (~50 lines) and replace them with this one function (7 lines).

---

The next block of code that I tackled is the portion where you set the vertices for a shape.  For example:

```
//losangle
                  losangleVertex[0].x = x;
                  losangleVertex[0].y = y;

                  losangleVertex[1].x = x + (size * cos((angle * PI) / 180));
                  losangleVertex[1].y = y + (size * (-sin((angle * PI) / 180)));

                  angle += 36;
                  losangleVertex[2].x = losangleVertex[1].x + size * cos((angle * PI) / 180);
                  losangleVertex[2].y = losangleVertex[1].y + size * (-sin((angle * PI) / 180));

                  angle += 144;
                  losangleVertex[3].x = losangleVertex[2].x + size * cos((angle * PI) / 180);
                  losangleVertex[3].y = losangleVertex[2].y + size * (-sin((angle * PI) / 180));
```

These blocks of code all follow the same basic structure and steps.

1. We start with the first point at `(x, y)`.
2. Each subsequent point is a transformation of the point before it (`losangleVertex[2] is based on losangleVertex[1])`
3. The `angle` variable is modified by a specific amount before each point.
4. Every `x` adds `size * cos((angle * PI) / 180)` and every `y` adds `size * (-sin((angle * PI) / 180));`

The core differences between the shapes are the angles (#3) and the amount of points.  We can provide an array containing all of the angle changes and the number of points will be based on the length of that array.

```
// uses global x, y, angle, size
function createShapeVertices(angleIncrements) {
  let vertices = [{ x, y }];
  for (let i = 0; i < angleIncrements.length; i++) {
    angle += angleIncrements[i];
    const previousPoint = vertices[i];
    const nextPoint = {
      x: previousPoint.x + size * cos((angle * PI) / 180),
      y: previousPoint.y + size * -sin((angle * PI) / 180)
    }
    vertices.push(nextPoint);
  }
  return vertices;
}
```

Note: There is another difference in your current code which is the variable where you are setting the points (ie. `losangleVertex`).  In my function I am just creating a new array and returning it.  Then assigning that returned array to the `losangleVertex` variable.  As a result you can delete all of the `losangleVertex[0] = new points();` from your `setup()` function and change `losangleVertex` from a global variable to a local variable of the `draw` function.

Your block of losangle vertex code can be replaced with a single line where we specify the changes to `angle`, which are +0, +36, +144.

```
losangleVertex = createShapeVertices([0, 36, 144]);
```

```
pentagonVertex = createShapeVertices([72, 72, 72, 72]);
```

```
harfStarVertex = createShapeVertices([-36, -72, 144, 36, 36, 144]);
```

```
starVertex = createShapeVertices([72, -72, 144, -72, 144, -72, 144, -72, 144]);
```

---

You can keep going down this path of extracting repetitive code into functions.  The next place I would look is all of your `list.insert()` statements.

```
var x, y, shape;
var angle;
var size = 20;
var tolerance = 0.00001;
var otherShapesAmount;
var sides;
var pentagonVertex = [];

// uses global x, y, angle, size
function createShapeVertices(angleIncrements) {
  let vertices = [{ x, y }];
  for (let i = 0; i < angleIncrements.length; i++) {
    angle += angleIncrements[i];
    const previousPoint = vertices[i];
    const nextPoint = {
      x: previousPoint.x + size * cos((angle * PI) / 180),
      y: previousPoint.y + size * -sin((angle * PI) / 180)
    }
    vertices.push(nextPoint);
  }
  return vertices;
}

function drawFromVertices(vertexArray) {
  beginShape();
  for (let i = 0; i < vertexArray.length; i++) {
    vertex(vertexArray[i].x, vertexArray[i].y);
  }
  endShape(CLOSE);
}

function list() {
  this.begin = null;
  this.size = 0;

  function no(x, y, angle, shape, otherShapesAmount, sides, next = null) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.angle = angle;
    this.shape = shape;
    this.otherShapesAmount = otherShapesAmount;
    this.sides = sides;
    this.next = next;
  }

  this.insert = function (x, y, angle, shape, otherShapesAmount, sides) {
    this.begin = new no(
      x,
      y,
      angle,
      shape,
      otherShapesAmount,
      sides,
      this.begin
    );
    this.size++;
  };

  this.differenceBetweenVertex = function (x, y, shape) {
    let atual = this.begin;

    while (atual) {
      if (atual.shape == shape)
        if (
          Math.abs(atual.x - x) < tolerance &&
          Math.abs(atual.y - y) < tolerance
        )
          return true;
      atual = atual.next;
    }
    return false;
  };

  this.getData = function () {
    if (this.size == 0) return 0;
    else if (this.size == 1) {
      x = this.begin.x;
      y = this.begin.y;
      angle = this.begin.angle;
      shape = this.begin.shape;
      otherShapesAmount = this.begin.otherShapesAmount;
      sides = this.begin.sides;

      this.begin = null;
    } else {
      var anterior;
      var auxiliar = 0;
      let atual = this.begin;
      while (auxiliar < this.size - 1) {
        anterior = atual;
        atual = atual.next;
        auxiliar++;
      }
      x = atual.x;
      y = atual.y;
      angle = atual.angle;
      shape = atual.shape;
      anterior.next = atual.next;
      otherShapesAmount = atual.otherShapesAmount;
      sides = atual.sides;
    }
    this.size--;
    return 1;
  };

  this.clean = function () {
    this.begin = null;
    this.size = 0;
  };
}

class points {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
}

function setup() {
  pentagonVertex[0] = new points();
  pentagonVertex[1] = new points();
  pentagonVertex[2] = new points();
  pentagonVertex[3] = new points();
  pentagonVertex[4] = new points();

  createCanvas(800, 800);
}

var mainList = new list();
var vertexList = new list();
var start = true;

function draw() {
  translate(800 / 2, 800 / 2);
  if (start == true) {
    //beginning - the cyan pentagon will nedd to be draw using the hypotenuse to be draw in the center of the translated point
    angle = 18;
    let hypotenuse = size / (2 * sin((36 * PI) / 180));
    pentagonVertex[0].x = hypotenuse * cos((angle * PI) / 180);
    pentagonVertex[0].y = hypotenuse * -sin((angle * PI) / 180);
    mainList.insert(
      pentagonVertex[0].x,
      pentagonVertex[0].y,
      angle - 18,
      1,
      1,
      undefined
    );
    mainList.insert(
      pentagonVertex[0].x,
      pentagonVertex[0].y,
      angle - 54,
      2,
      10,
      undefined
    );
    angle += 72;
    pentagonVertex[1].x = hypotenuse * cos((angle * PI) / 180);
    pentagonVertex[1].y = hypotenuse * -sin((angle * PI) / 180);
    mainList.insert(
      pentagonVertex[1].x,
      pentagonVertex[1].y,
      angle - 18,
      1,
      1,
      undefined
    );
    mainList.insert(
      pentagonVertex[1].x,
      pentagonVertex[1].y,
      angle - 54,
      2,
      10,
      undefined
    );
    angle += 72;
    pentagonVertex[2].x = hypotenuse * cos((angle * PI) / 180);
    pentagonVertex[2].y = hypotenuse * -sin((angle * PI) / 180);
    mainList.insert(
      pentagonVertex[2].x,
      pentagonVertex[2].y,
      angle - 18,
      1,
      1,
      undefined
    );
    mainList.insert(
      pentagonVertex[2].x,
      pentagonVertex[2].y,
      angle - 54,
      2,
      10,
      undefined
    );
    angle += 72;
    pentagonVertex[3].x = hypotenuse * cos((angle * PI) / 180);
    pentagonVertex[3].y = hypotenuse * -sin((angle * PI) / 180);
    mainList.insert(
      pentagonVertex[3].x,
      pentagonVertex[3].y,
      angle - 18,
      1,
      1,
      undefined
    );
    mainList.insert(
      pentagonVertex[3].x,
      pentagonVertex[3].y,
      angle - 54,
      2,
      10,
      undefined
    );
    angle += 72;
    pentagonVertex[4].x = hypotenuse * cos((angle * PI) / 180);
    pentagonVertex[4].y = hypotenuse * -sin((angle * PI) / 180);
    mainList.insert(pentagonVertex[4].x, pentagonVertex[4].y, angle - 18, 1, 1);
    mainList.insert(
      pentagonVertex[4].x,
      pentagonVertex[4].y,
      angle - 54,
      2,
      10,
      undefined
    );

    fill("cyan");
    drawFromVertices(pentagonVertex);
    start = false;
  } else {
    while (mainList.getData()) {
      switch (shape) {
        case 0:
          if (vertexList.differenceBetweenVertex(x, y, 0) == false) {
            //cyan pentagon
            pentagonVertex = createShapeVertices([72, 72, 72, 72]);

            fill("cyan");
            drawFromVertices(pentagonVertex);
            mainList.insert(
              pentagonVertex[2].x,
              pentagonVertex[2].y,
              angle + 144,
              1,
              1,
              sides
            );
            vertexList.insert(
              pentagonVertex[1].x,
              pentagonVertex[1].y,
              null,
              0,
              undefined,
              undefined
            );
            vertexList.insert(
              pentagonVertex[3].x,
              pentagonVertex[3].y,
              null,
              0,
              undefined,
              undefined
            );
            vertexList.insert(
              pentagonVertex[4].x,
              pentagonVertex[4].y,
              null,
              0,
              undefined,
              undefined
            );
          } else {
            let auxiliar = 0;
            pentagonVertex[0].x = x;
            pentagonVertex[0].y = y;

            if (vertexList.differenceBetweenVertex(x, y, 1) == true) auxiliar++;
            angle += 180;

            pentagonVertex[1].x = x + size * cos((angle * PI) / 180);
            pentagonVertex[1].y = y + size * -sin((angle * PI) / 180);
            if (
              vertexList.differenceBetweenVertex(
                pentagonVertex[1].x,
                pentagonVertex[1].y,
                1
              ) == true
            )
              auxiliar++;

            angle -= 72;
            pentagonVertex[2].x =
              pentagonVertex[1].x + size * cos((angle * PI) / 180);
            pentagonVertex[2].y =
              pentagonVertex[1].y + size * -sin((angle * PI) / 180);
            if (
              vertexList.differenceBetweenVertex(
                pentagonVertex[2].x,
                pentagonVertex[2].y,
                1
              ) == true
            )
              auxiliar++;

            angle -= 72;
            pentagonVertex[3].x =
              pentagonVertex[2].x + size * cos((angle * PI) / 180);
            pentagonVertex[3].y =
              pentagonVertex[2].y + size * -sin((angle * PI) / 180);

            if (
              vertexList.differenceBetweenVertex(
                pentagonVertex[3].x,
                pentagonVertex[3].y,
                1
              ) == false
            ) {
              mainList.insert(
                pentagonVertex[3].x,
                pentagonVertex[3].y,
                angle + 36,
                1,
                1
              );
              vertexList.insert(
                pentagonVertex[3].x,
                pentagonVertex[3].y,
                null,
                1
              );
            }
            auxiliar++;

            angle -= 72;
            pentagonVertex[4].x =
              pentagonVertex[3].x + size * cos((angle * PI) / 180);
            pentagonVertex[4].y =
              pentagonVertex[3].y + size * -sin((angle * PI) / 180);
            if (
              vertexList.differenceBetweenVertex(
                pentagonVertex[4].x,
                pentagonVertex[4].y,
                1
              ) == true
            )
              auxiliar++;

            if (auxiliar == 3)
              mainList.insert(
                pentagonVertex[1].x,
                pentagonVertex[1].y,
                angle + 216,
                2,
                10,
                undefined
              );
            else {
              mainList.insert(
                pentagonVertex[0].x,
                pentagonVertex[0].y,
                angle - 72,
                2,
                7,
                1
              );
              mainList.insert(
                pentagonVertex[3].x,
                pentagonVertex[3].y,
                angle + 72,
                2,
                7,
                0
              );
              mainList.insert(
                pentagonVertex[4].x,
                pentagonVertex[4].y,
                angle,
                2,
                3,
                undefined
              );
            }
          }
          break;
        case 1:
          const losangleVertex = createShapeVertices([0, 36, 144]);

          fill("yellow");
          drawFromVertices(losangleVertex);
          mainList.insert(
            losangleVertex[2].x,
            losangleVertex[2].y,
            angle - 288,
            0,
            1,
            undefined
          );
          vertexList.insert(x, y, null, 1, 0, undefined);
          vertexList.insert(
            losangleVertex[2].x,
            losangleVertex[2].y,
            null,
            1,
            0,
            undefined
          );
          break;
        case 2:
          otherShapesAmount--; //gray pentagon
          pentagonVertex = createShapeVertices([72, 72, 72, 72]);

          fill("gray");
          drawFromVertices(pentagonVertex);
          if (otherShapesAmount > 1) {
            mainList.insert(
              pentagonVertex[1].x,
              pentagonVertex[1].y,
              angle + 36,
              3,
              1,
              sides
            );
            if (otherShapesAmount > 5)
              mainList.insert(
                pentagonVertex[2].x,
                pentagonVertex[2].y,
                angle + 180,
                4,
                otherShapesAmount - 2,
                sides
              );
            mainList.insert(
              pentagonVertex[3].x,
              pentagonVertex[3].y,
              angle - 324,
              3,
              1,
              sides
            );
          } else
            mainList.insert(
              pentagonVertex[2].x,
              pentagonVertex[2].y,
              angle + 108,
              3,
              1,
              sides
            );
          break;
        case 3:
          otherShapesAmount--; //red pentagon
          pentagonVertex = createShapeVertices([72, 72, 72, 72]);

          fill("red");
          drawFromVertices(pentagonVertex);
          if (otherShapesAmount > 0)
            mainList.insert(
              pentagonVertex[3].x,
              pentagonVertex[3].y,
              angle - 324,
              5,
              otherShapesAmount,
              sides
            );
          break;
        case 4:
          otherShapesAmount--; //half star
          const harfStarVertex = createShapeVertices([-36, -72, 144, 36, 36, 144]);
          
          fill("green");
          drawFromVertices(harfStarVertex);
          if (otherShapesAmount > 5) {
            mainList.insert(
              harfStarVertex[2].x,
              harfStarVertex[2].y,
              angle - 36,
              2,
              2,
              undefined
            );
            mainList.insert(
              harfStarVertex[3].x,
              harfStarVertex[3].y,
              angle,
              3,
              2,
              undefined
            );
            mainList.insert(
              harfStarVertex[5].x,
              harfStarVertex[5].y,
              angle - 36,
              2,
              2,
              undefined
            );
          } else if (sides == 0)
            mainList.insert(
              harfStarVertex[5].x,
              harfStarVertex[5].y,
              angle - 36,
              2,
              2,
              sides
            );
          else
            mainList.insert(
              harfStarVertex[2].x,
              harfStarVertex[2].y,
              angle - 36,
              2,
              2,
              sides
            );
          break;
        default:
          const starVertex = createShapeVertices([72, -72, 144, -72, 144, -72, 144, -72, 144]);
    
          fill("orange");
          drawFromVertices(starVertex);
      }
    }
    noLoop();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Linda!!!! Your help was very useful!

Answer (score 0):

```html
 <html>
  <head>
    <meta charset = "utf-8">
    <title>Penrose</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.6.0/p5.js"></script>
  <script>

  var x, y, shape;
  var angle;
  var size = 20;
  var tolerance = 0.00001;
  var otherShapesAmount;
  var sides;

function list()
{
  this.begin = null;
  this.size = 0;

  function no(x, y, angle, shape, otherShapesAmount, sides, next = null)
  {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.angle = angle;
    this.shape = shape;
    this.otherShapesAmount = otherShapesAmount;
    this.sides = sides;
    this.next = next;
  }

  this.insert = function(x, y, angle, shape, otherShapesAmount, sides)
  {
    this.begin = new no(x, y, angle, shape, otherShapesAmount, sides, this.begin);
    this.size++;
  }

  this.differenceBetweenVertex = function(x, y, shape)
  {
    let atual = this.begin;

    while (atual) {
      if (atual.shape == shape && Math.abs(atual.x - x) < tolerance && Math.abs(atual.y - y) < tolerance) {
         return true;
      }
      atual = atual.next;
    }
    return false;
  }

  this.getData = function()
  {
    if (this.size == 0) return 0;
      else if (this.size == 1)
      {
        x = this.begin.x;
        y = this.begin.y;
        angle = this.begin.angle;
        shape = this.begin.shape;
        otherShapesAmount = this.begin.otherShapesAmount;
        sides = this.begin.sides;
        
        this.begin = null;
      }
        else
        {
          var anterior;
          var auxiliar = 0;
          let atual = this.begin;
          while (auxiliar < this.size - 1)
          {
            anterior = atual;
            atual = atual.next;
            auxiliar++;
          }
          x = atual.x;
          y = atual.y;
          angle = atual.angle;
          shape = atual.shape;
          anterior.next = atual.next;
          otherShapesAmount = atual.otherShapesAmount;
          sides = atual.sides;
       }
    this.size--;
    return 1;
  }

  this.clean = function() {
    this.begin = null;
    this.size = 0;
  }
}

class points
{
  constructor(x, y)
  {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
}

  var pentagonVertex = [];
  var losangleVertex = [];
  var harfStarVertex = [];
  var starVertex = [];

function setup()
{
    for (let i = 0; i <= 4; i++) pentagonVertex[i] = new points();
  for (let i = 0; i <= 3; i++) losangleVertex[i] = new points();
  for (let i = 0; i <= 6; i++) harfStarVertex[i] = new points();
    for (let i = 0; i <= 9; i++) starVertex[i] = new points();

  createCanvas(800, 800);
}

function drawPentagon(pentagonVertex) {
  beginShape();
  for (let i = 0; i <= 5; i++) vertex(pentagonVertex[i % 5].x, pentagonVertex[i % 5].y)
  endShape();
}

function drawLosangle(losangleVertex) {
  beginShape()
  for (let i = 0; i <= 4; i++) vertex(losangleVertex[i % 4].x, losangleVertex[i % 4].y)
  endShape();
}

function drawHalfStar(harfStarVertex)
{
  beginShape();
  for (let i = 0; i <= 7; i++) vertex(harfStarVertex[i % 7].x, harfStarVertex[i % 7].y)
  endShape();
}

function drawStar(starVertex)
{
  beginShape();
  for (let i = 0; i <= 10; i++) vertex(starVertex[i % 10].x, starVertex[i % 10].y);
  endShape();
}

  var mainList = new list();
  var vertexList = new list();
  var start = true;

function draw()
{
  translate (800 / 2, 800 / 2);
  if (start == true) //beginning - the cyan pentagon will nedd to be draw using the hypotenuse to be draw in the center of the translated point
  {
    angle = 18;
    let hypotenuse = size / (2 * sin((36 * PI) / 180));
    for (let i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
        pentagonVertex[i].x = hypotenuse * cos((angle * PI) / 180);
        pentagonVertex[i].y = hypotenuse * (-sin((angle * PI) / 180));
        mainList.insert(pentagonVertex[i].x, pentagonVertex[i].y, angle - 18, 1, 1);
        mainList.insert(pentagonVertex[i].x, pentagonVertex[i].y, angle - 54, 2, 10);
        angle += 72;
    }

    fill('cyan');
    drawPentagon(pentagonVertex);
    start = false;
  }
    else
    {
      while (mainList.getData())
      {
        switch (shape) {
          case 0: if (vertexList.differenceBetweenVertex(x, y, 0) == false) //cyan pentagon
                  {
                    pentagonVertex[0].x = x;
                    pentagonVertex[0].y = y;

                    angle += 72;
                    pentagonVertex[1].x = x + size * cos((angle * PI) / 180);
                    pentagonVertex[1].y = y + (size * (-sin((angle * PI) / 180)));

                    angle += 72;
                    pentagonVertex[2].x = pentagonVertex[1].x + size * cos((angle * PI) / 180);
                    pentagonVertex[2].y = pentagonVertex[1].y + size * (-sin((angle * PI) / 180));

                    angle += 72;
                    pentagonVertex[3].x = pentagonVertex[2].x + size * cos((angle * PI) / 180);
                    pentagonVertex[3].y = pentagonVertex[2].y + size * (-sin((angle * PI) / 180));

                    angle += 72;
                    pentagonVertex[4].x = pentagonVertex[3].x + size * cos((angle * PI) / 180);
                    pentagonVertex[4].y = pentagonVertex[3].y + size * (-sin((angle * PI) / 180));

                    fill('cyan');
                    drawPentagon(pentagonVertex);
                    mainList.insert(pentagonVertex[2].x, pentagonVertex[2].y, angle + 144, 1, 1, sides);
                    vertexList.insert(pentagonVertex[1].x, pentagonVertex[1].y, null, 0, );
                    vertexList.insert(pentagonVertex[3].x, pentagonVertex[3].y, null, 0);
                    vertexList.insert(pentagonVertex[4].x, pentagonVertex[4].y, null, 0);
                  }
                    else
                    {
                      let auxiliar = 0;
                      pentagonVertex[0].x = x;
                      pentagonVertex[0].y = y;

                      if (vertexList.differenceBetweenVertex(x, y, 1) == true) auxiliar++;
                      angle += 180;
              
                      pentagonVertex[1].x = x + size * cos((angle * PI) / 180);
                      pentagonVertex[1].y = y + size * (-sin((angle * PI) / 180));
                      if (vertexList.differenceBetweenVertex(pentagonVertex[1].x, pentagonVertex[1].y, 1) == true) auxiliar++;

                      angle -= 72;
                      pentagonVertex[2].x = pentagonVertex[1].x + size * cos((angle * PI) / 180);
                      pentagonVertex[2].y = pentagonVertex[1].y + size * (-sin((angle * PI) / 180));
                      if (vertexList.differenceBetweenVertex(pentagonVertex[2].x, pentagonVertex[2].y, 1) == true) auxiliar++;

                      angle -= 72;
                      pentagonVertex[3].x = pentagonVertex[2].x + size * cos((angle * PI) / 180);
                      pentagonVertex[3].y = pentagonVertex[2].y + size * (-sin((angle * PI) / 180));

                      if (vertexList.differenceBetweenVertex(pentagonVertex[3].x, pentagonVertex[3].y, 1) == false)
                      {
                        mainList.insert(pentagonVertex[3].x, pentagonVertex[3].y, angle + 36, 1,1);
                        vertexList.insert(pentagonVertex[3].x, pentagonVertex[3].y, null,1);
                      }
                      auxiliar++;

                      angle -= 72;
                      pentagonVertex[4].x = pentagonVertex[3].x + size * cos((angle * PI) / 180);
                      pentagonVertex[4].y = pentagonVertex[3].y + size * (-sin((angle * PI) / 180));
                      if (vertexList.differenceBetweenVertex(pentagonVertex[4].x, pentagonVertex[4].y, 1) == true) auxiliar++;

                      if (auxiliar == 3) mainList.insert(pentagonVertex[1].x, pentagonVertex[1].y, angle + 216, 2, 10, undefined);
                        else
                        {
                          mainList.insert(pentagonVertex[0].x, pentagonVertex[0].y, angle - 72, 2, 7, 1);
                          mainList.insert(pentagonVertex[3].x, pentagonVertex[3].y, angle + 72, 2, 7, 0);
                          mainList.insert(pentagonVertex[4].x, pentagonVertex[4].y, angle, 2, 3, undefined);
                        }
                    }
          break;
          case 1: losangleVertex[0].x = x; //losangle
                  losangleVertex[0].y = y;

                  losangleVertex[1].x = x + (size * cos((angle * PI) / 180));
                  losangleVertex[1].y = y + (size * (-sin((angle * PI) / 180)));

                  angle += 36;
                  losangleVertex[2].x = losangleVertex[1].x + size * cos((angle * PI) / 180);
                  losangleVertex[2].y = losangleVertex[1].y + size * (-sin((angle * PI) / 180));

                  angle += 144;
                  losangleVertex[3].x = losangleVertex[2].x + size * cos((angle * PI) / 180);
                  losangleVertex[3].y = losangleVertex[2].y + size * (-sin((angle * PI) / 180));

                  fill('yellow');
                  drawLosangle(losangleVertex);
                  mainList.insert(losangleVertex[2].x, losangleVertex[2].y, angle - 288, 0, 1, undefined);
                  vertexList.insert(x, y, null, 1, 0, undefined);
                  vertexList.insert(losangleVertex[2].x, losangleVertex[2].y, null, 1, 0, undefined);
          break;
          case 2: otherShapesAmount--; //gray pentagon
                  pentagonVertex[0].x = x;
                  pentagonVertex[0].y = y;

                  angle += 72;
                  pentagonVertex[1].x = x + size * cos((angle * PI) / 180);
                  pentagonVertex[1].y = y + (size * (-sin((angle * PI) / 180)));

                  angle += 72;
                  pentagonVertex[2].x = pentagonVertex[1].x + size * cos((angle * PI) / 180);
                  pentagonVertex[2].y = pentagonVertex[1].y + size * (-sin((angle * PI) / 180));

                  angle += 72;
                  pentagonVertex[3].x = pentagonVertex[2].x + size * cos((angle * PI) / 180);
                  pentagonVertex[3].y = pentagonVertex[2].y + size * (-sin((angle * PI) / 180));

                  angle += 72;
                  pentagonVertex[4].x = pentagonVertex[3].x + size * cos((angle * PI) / 180);
                  pentagonVertex[4].y = pentagonVertex[3].y + size * (-sin((angle * PI) / 180));

                  fill('gray');
                  drawPentagon(pentagonVertex);
                  if (otherShapesAmount > 1)
                  {
                    mainList.insert(pentagonVertex[1].x, pentagonVertex[1].y, angle + 36, 3, 1, sides);
                    if (otherShapesAmount > 5) mainList.insert(pentagonVertex[2].x, pentagonVertex[2].y, angle + 180, 4, otherShapesAmount - 2, sides);
                    mainList.insert(pentagonVertex[3].x, pentagonVertex[3].y, angle - 324, 3, 1, sides);
                  }
                    else mainList.insert(pentagonVertex[2].x, pentagonVertex[2].y, angle + 108, 3, 1, sides);
          break;
          case 3: otherShapesAmount--; //red pentagon
                  pentagonVertex[0].x = x;
                  pentagonVertex[0].y = y;
                  angle += 72;
                  pentagonVertex[1].x = x + size * cos((angle * PI) / 180);
                  pentagonVertex[1].y = y + (size * (-sin((angle * PI) / 180)));

                  angle += 72;
                  pentagonVertex[2].x = pentagonVertex[1].x + size * cos((angle * PI) / 180);
                  pentagonVertex[2].y = pentagonVertex[1].y + size * (-sin((angle * PI) / 180));

                  angle += 72;
                  pentagonVertex[3].x = pentagonVertex[2].x + size * cos((angle * PI) / 180);
                  pentagonVertex[3].y = pentagonVertex[2].y + size * (-sin((angle * PI) / 180));

                  angle += 72;
                  pentagonVertex[4].x = pentagonVertex[3].x + size * cos((angle * PI) / 180);
                  pentagonVertex[4].y = pentagonVertex[3].y + size * (-sin((angle * PI) / 180));
            
                  fill('red');
                  drawPentagon(pentagonVertex);
                  if (otherShapesAmount > 0) mainList.insert(pentagonVertex[3].x, pentagonVertex[3].y, angle - 324, 5, otherShapesAmount, sides);
          break;
          case 4: otherShapesAmount--; //half star
                  harfStarVertex[0].x = x;
                  harfStarVertex[0].y = y;

                  angle -= 36;
                  harfStarVertex[1].x = x + size * cos((angle * PI) / 180);
                  harfStarVertex[1].y = y + size * (-sin((angle * PI) / 180));

                  angle -= 72;
                  harfStarVertex[2].x = harfStarVertex[1].x + size * cos((angle * PI) / 180);
                  harfStarVertex[2].y = harfStarVertex[1].y + size * (-sin((angle * PI) / 180));

                  angle += 144;
                  harfStarVertex[3].x = harfStarVertex[2].x + size * cos((angle * PI) / 180);
                  harfStarVertex[3].y = harfStarVertex[2].y + size * (-sin((angle * PI) / 180));

                  angle += 36;
                  harfStarVertex[4].x = harfStarVertex[3].x + size * cos((angle * PI) / 180);
                  harfStarVertex[4].y = harfStarVertex[3].y + size * (-sin((angle * PI) / 180));

                  angle += 36;
                  harfStarVertex[5].x = harfStarVertex[4].x + size * cos((angle * PI) / 180);
                  harfStarVertex[5].y = harfStarVertex[4].y + size * (-sin((angle * PI) / 180));

                  angle += 144;
                  harfStarVertex[6].x = harfStarVertex[5].x + size * cos((angle * PI) / 180);
                  harfStarVertex[6].y = harfStarVertex[5].y + size * (-sin((angle * PI) / 180));
                  fill('green');
                  drawHalfStar(harfStarVertex);
                  if (otherShapesAmount > 5)
                  {
                    mainList.insert(harfStarVertex[2].x, harfStarVertex[2].y, angle - 36, 2, 2, undefined);
                    mainList.insert(harfStarVertex[3].x, harfStarVertex[3].y, angle, 3, 2, undefined);
                    mainList.insert(harfStarVertex[5].x, harfStarVertex[5].y, angle- 36, 2, 2, undefined);
                  }
                    else if (sides == 0) mainList.insert(harfStarVertex[5].x, harfStarVertex[5].y, angle - 36, 2, 2, sides);
                      else mainList.insert(harfStarVertex[2].x, harfStarVertex[2].y, angle - 36, 2, 2, sides);
          break;
          default: starVertex[0].x = x; //star
                   starVertex[0].y = y;

                   angle += 72;
                   starVertex[1].x = x + size * cos((angle * PI) / 180);
                   starVertex[1].y = y + size * (-sin((angle * PI) / 180));

                   angle -= 72;
                   starVertex[2].x = starVertex[1].x + size * cos((angle * PI) / 180);
                   starVertex[2].y = starVertex[1].y + size * (-sin((angle * PI) / 180));

                   angle += 144;
                   starVertex[3].x = starVertex[2].x + size * cos((angle * PI) / 180);
                   starVertex[3].y = starVertex[2].y + size * (-sin((angle * PI) / 180));

                   angle -= 72;
                   starVertex[4].x = starVertex[3].x + size * cos((angle * PI) / 180);
                   starVertex[4].y = starVertex[3].y + size * (-sin((angle * PI) / 180));

                   angle += 144;
                   starVertex[5].x = starVertex[4].x + size * cos((angle * PI) / 180);
                   starVertex[5].y = starVertex[4].y + size * (-sin((angle * PI) / 180));

                   angle -= 72;
                   starVertex[6].x = starVertex[5].x + size * cos((angle * PI) / 180);
                   starVertex[6].y = starVertex[5].y + size * (-sin((angle * PI) / 180));

                   angle += 144;
                   starVertex[7].x = starVertex[6].x + size * cos((angle * PI) / 180);
                   starVertex[7].y = starVertex[6].y + size * (-sin((angle * PI) / 180));

                   angle -= 72;
                   starVertex[8].x = starVertex[7].x + size * cos((angle * PI) / 180);
                   starVertex[8].y = starVertex[7].y + size * (-sin((angle * PI) / 180));

                   angle += 144;
                   starVertex[9].x = starVertex[8].x + size * cos((angle * PI) / 180);
                   starVertex[9].y = starVertex[8].y + size * (-sin((angle * PI) / 180));

                   fill('orange');
                   drawStar(starVertex);
        }
      }
      noLoop();
    }
}
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```